# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql

The Error of mysql is following.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'message.msg_type=R GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id ORDER BY
>   ticket.created DESC LIMIT ' at line 1

The query is following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ticket.ticket_id,lock_id,ticketID,ticket.dept_id,ticket.staff_id,subject,ticket.name,ticket.email,dept_name,lastresponse
    ,ticket.status,ticket.source,message.message,isoverdue,isanswered,ticket.created,pri.*
    ,count(attach.attach_id) as attachments
    ,staff.firstname,staff.lastname , IF(ticket.reopened is
    NULL,ticket.created,ticket.reopened) as effective_date FROM
    kt_ticket ticket LEFT JOIN kt_department dept ON ticket.dept_id =
    dept.dept_id LEFT JOIN kt_priority pri ON
    ticket.priority_id=pri.priority_id LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_lock tlock ON
    ticket.ticket_id=tlock.ticket_id AND tlock.expire>NOW() LEFT JOIN
    kt_ticket_attachment attach ON ticket.ticket_id=attach.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_message message ON
    (ticket.ticket_id=message.ticket_id ) LEFT JOIN kt_staff staff ON
    ticket.staff_id=staff.staff_id WHERE 1=1 AND status='open' AND
    ticket.pp_group =1 message.msg_type=R GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id
    ORDER BY ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

---

Answer (score 3):

There is a missing `AND` clause between following two conditions.

```
ticket.pp_group =1
```

AND

```
message.msg_type=R
```

Also the `R` should be quoted with single quotes, as you are comparing `chracter`.

So that would look something like this,

```
AND ticket.pp_group =1 AND message.msg_type='R'
```

Comment: You're welcome, Please accept it as correct answer when its allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The strings should be quoted and a missing 'AND'

```
[...] AND message.msg_type='R' [...]
```

The error message points you to that direction, even though it is a bit vague.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you, please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write and between two where condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket.ticket_id,
                lock_id,
                ticketID,
                ticket.dept_id,
                ticket.staff_id,
                subject,
                ticket.name,
                ticket.email,
                dept_name,
                lastresponse,
                ticket.status,
                ticket.source,
                message.message,
                isoverdue,
                isanswered,
                ticket.created,
                pri.*,
                count(attach.attach_id) AS attachments,
                staff.firstname,
                staff.lastname,
                IF(ticket.reopened IS NULL,ticket.created,ticket.reopened) AS effective_date
FROM kt_ticket ticket
LEFT JOIN kt_department dept ON ticket.dept_id = dept.dept_id
LEFT JOIN kt_priority pri ON ticket.priority_id=pri.priority_id
LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_lock tlock ON ticket.ticket_id=tlock.ticket_id
AND tlock.expire>NOW()
LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_attachment attach ON ticket.ticket_id=attach.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_message message ON (ticket.ticket_id=message.ticket_id)
LEFT JOIN kt_staff staff ON ticket.staff_id=staff.staff_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND status='open'
  AND ticket.pp_group =1 AND message.msg_type=R
GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket.ticket_id,lock_id,ticketID,ticket.dept_id,ticket.staff_id,subject,ticket.name,ticket.email,dept_name,lastresponse ,ticket.status,ticket.source,message.message,isoverdue,isanswered,ticket.created,pri.* ,count(attach.attach_id) as attachments ,staff.firstname,staff.lastname , IF(ticket.reopened is NULL,ticket.created,ticket.reopened) as effective_date FROM kt_ticket ticket LEFT JOIN kt_department dept ON ticket.dept_id = dept.dept_id LEFT JOIN kt_priority pri ON ticket.priority_id=pri.priority_id LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_lock tlock ON ticket.ticket_id=tlock.ticket_id AND tlock.expire>NOW() LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_attachment attach ON ticket.ticket_id=attach.ticket_id LEFT JOIN kt_ticket_message message ON (ticket.ticket_id=message.ticket_id ) LEFT JOIN kt_staff staff ON ticket.staff_id=staff.staff_id WHERE 1=1 AND status='open' AND ticket.pp_group = 1 AND message.msg_type=R GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id ORDER BY ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

first there is an `AND` missing:  ticket.pp_group =1 **AND** message.msg_type=R GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id ORDER BY ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0,25

second strings must be quoted by single quote:  message.msg_type='R'

So the last part must be:

```
ticket.pp_group =1 AND message.msg_type='R' GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id ORDER BY ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0,25
```